# Struts2 MessageResources in Apache Tiles

Tags: struts2, tiles2

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use a Struts2 message resource in a tiles
2.1.4 expression. For example the following resource is available in
the JSP...

```jsp
<s:text name="htmlheadHeading1"/><br/>
```

... but when I attempt to use the same resource in the tiles definition...

```jsp
<put-attribute name="title" expression="${htmlheadHeading1}" />
```

... I get the error...

```jsp
ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'htmlheadHeading1'
```

... Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Where your `htmlheadHeading1` comes from?

Comment: from the struts2 message resource (i18n).

Comment: I'm quite sure there is not a way to do what you want, given that you specify tiles version 2.1.4 however if you go to tiles version 2.2.2 or the now current tiles 3 you can use OGNL expressions in tiles definitions and then do things as directly as you hoped.

Comment: That sounds good. I was unable to get tiles 2.2.2 to work with struts2. I'll have to put that on the backburner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not use tiles expressions but will work if you need to display localized text in JSP when key is passed through tiles definitions.

In tiles definition:

```
<put-attribute name="title" value="htmlheadHeading1" />
```

In your JSP then use Struts2 `<s:set>` tag to set title from tiles definition to local variable and then use it in `<s:text>` tag.

```
<s:set var="title">
  <tiles:getAsString name="title" ignore="true"/>
</s:set>
<s:text name="%{#title}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this does work for messages from the tiles definition to a struts2 tag. I still have not been able to resolve how to get messages from struts2 to the tiles definition.

Comment: the goal is to keep all messages in one place.

Comment: What do you mean? All messages is in the properties files. And that is just a key. What you want to do with text from properties files in tiles definition?

Comment: Let's make sure we're on the same page. What do you get as the final value for <s:text name="%{#title}"/>?

Comment: The text with key `htmlheadHeading1` from properties file. What do you think? :)

Comment: I apologize, I had already been working on a tiles.xml centric solution and got the two mixed up when testing. You are correct! this works!!