# struts 2 tiles with parameter at runtime

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles2

I have an internationalized application and I'm trying to read the key files of resources in the title of a page layout loaded through the tiles listener.

The configuration of my tiles.xml is the following:

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/template/01/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Value at runtime" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/welcome.jsp" />
</definition>
```

inside the page baseLayout.jsp I entered:

```
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"/></title>
```

I want to insert at runtime the value that today something is inserted by hand.
below the line:

```
<put-attribute name="title" value="Value at runtime" type="string" />
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13920587/1700321.